# Move function to another js file

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript and Electron. The app has an entry point named 'main.js'. I am just getting familiar with making calls to an API, so the scripts at the moment are very basic and don't have any frontend. Basically, I am logging in, getting some data and logging out. It all works fine when the functions are in main.js, but now I am trying to move one of the functions to a different .js file and, depending on whether I use the import or require keywords and syntax, I get either the 'Cannot use import statement outside a module' or the 'xxx is not a function' errors. I also tried to change the extension as 'main.mjs' (I read this in another post as a possible solution) but it does not work. Obviously, I'm doing something wrong, but I can't understand what. Would anyone be so kind as to explain?

This is the code for 'main.js':

```
import auth from './auth.js';

// disable the server's self-signed certificate validation
process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0'

const serviceLayer = 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50000/b1s/v1/'
const data = {
    "CompanyDB": "myDB",
    "UserName": "myUsername",
    "Password": "myPassword"
}

const login = async () => {
    try {
        const url = serviceLayer + 'Login'
        const customHeaders = {
            'Content-Type': "application/json",
        }

        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: customHeaders,
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            credentials: 'include' // include cookies in the request
        })

        const cookiesArray = response.headers.getSetCookie()
        const sessionId = cookiesArray[0].substring(10, 68)
        const node = cookiesArray[1].substring(8, 14)
        const cookies = {
            'B1SESSION': sessionId,
            'ROUTEID': node
        }

        return cookies
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

const getOwor = async (session, node, id) => {
    try {
        const url = serviceLayer + 'ProductionOrders(' + id + ')'
        const customHeaders = {
            'Content-Type': "application/json",
            'Cookie': "B1SESSION=" + session + ";ROUTEID=" + node
        }

        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: customHeaders
        })

        const json = response.json()
        return json
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

(async function () {
    const cookies = await login();
    console.log(cookies)
    const owor = await getOwor(cookies['B1SESSION'], cookies['ROUTEID'], 87);
    console.log(owor)
    const logoutStatus = await auth.logout(cookies['B1SESSION'], cookies['ROUTEID']);
    console.log(logoutStatus)
    process.exit()
})()
```

This is the code for 'auth.js':

```
const logout = async (session, node) => {
    try {
        const url = serviceLayer + 'Logout'
        const customHeaders = {
            'Content-Type': "application/json",
            'Cookie': "B1SESSION=" + session + ";ROUTEID=" + node
        }

        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: customHeaders,
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })

        const status = response.status
        return status
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

export default logout
```

And, finally, this is the error:

> Uncaught Exception: C:......\main.js:1
> import auth from './auth.js';
> Syntax error: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: Inside **package.json** make sure you define: `type: "module"` then you can use ES `import` declaration. (Or you could run `node` with flag `--experimental-default-type` as per [this discussion](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/50096))

Comment: There is no mention of Node.js in the question, so this comment above is not relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I stumbled across another piece of code and I noticed a different syntax for the module.exports statement and it worked. The code now looks like this:
In `main.js`

```
const auth = require('./auth')
```

In `auth.js`

```
module.exports = {
    logout: logout
}
```

Comment: Tag this answer as solved so others may find it helpful

Answer (score 1):

if you have an HTML file make sure you defined in `<script src="..."  type: "module">` 
or define it in package.json

Comment: Thank you @daniel-hakobyan but I am not using an HTML file yet. And even then, using electron.js, these scripts would live in the backend anyway

Answer (score 0):

Please forget what other answers say about `"type": "module"`: this is a Node.js only approach to module resolution and has nothing to do with JavaScript and your question.

To expose JavaScript modules, just name your modules with the `.mjs` extensions instead of `.js`. `.mjs` is the natively supported extensions for ES modules, and is mandatory for modules that either want to use the `import` or `export` syntax.

Since your main entry point is already a proper ES module (`main.mjs`), you just need to also make `auth` a proper ES module by renaming `auth.js` to `auth.mjs`.

And of course import it in `main.mjs` using its proper extension:

```
import auth from './auth.mjs';
```

Comment: OP mentioned that they're working with electron so they're obviously using node.js

Comment: No, they aren't. First, Electron can function with other runtimes. Second it is perfectly possible to execute a ES module using Node.js _without_ a package.json file. Node.js would then honor ES module specifications. Please let's stop confusion everything. Node.js is just a runtime that honors ECMAScript and ES modules specications. There is no need for a Node.js specific solution when there is a generic ES Module one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that no tutorial would tell someone to use Electron.js without Node.js. OP mentioned that they're learning so they're probably using a tutorial that tells the learners to use Node.js. I'm certain that OP is using Node.js. No sane learner would not want to use Node.js

Comment: Well, a sane learner would want to understand the language (JavaScript and ES modules spec) before Node.js. And still, there is no guarantee that a package.json file is deployed in the end - it is likely that it is not, based on the fact that 100% of the Node.js applications that we deploy don't come with a package.json file.

Comment: I just used `create-electron-app`, the most basic package that every new learner would use to build an electron app, and made a sample one. And yes, it came with a `package.json` file. Try it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Add `"type":"module"` to your `package.json` file.

```json
{
  "type": "module",
}
```

This should fix the issue.

Comment: There is no mention of Node.js in the question, so this answer is not relevant.

Comment: @EricMORAND Electron.js uses node. OP mentioned that they're using electron.

Comment: Electron.js doesn't use Node.js. It does not even make sense to say so. Electron.js works with any ECMAScript runtime - we can totally make it work with deno or inside a browser (yep, it is perfectly possible to provide all the needed libraries in a browser environment). Anyway, ES modules have nothing to do with Node.js, and the solution is just to honor ES module specifications. Mentioning a Node.js only solution maintains the confusion between Node.js and JavaScript.

Comment: But do you really expect someone to use Electron.js to run their app on the browser? Electron.js is used to make desktop apps and Node.js is a must for that. It doesn't work without it.

Comment: That's not my point. You gave a node.js answer based on package.json when you don't know if node.js is used _or_ if a package.json is deployed alongside the application - and if you can argue that node.js is likely used, I can argue that a package.json is likely to not be present when the app is deployed.

Comment: Welp, only OP can settle this by providing further information but both of our answers will be useful to him even if he uses Node.js

Comment: Thank you both for trying to help. I just ran "npm install electron.js", but I'm guessing my code is plain javascript at the moment? Anyway, I tried both your solutions and they both return "TypeError: auth.logout is not a function". And yes, there is a package.json file